# Why is the Linux kernel in main?

Tags: kernel, free-software

[According to GNU](https://www.gnu.org/distros/common-distros.html), there are nonfree binary blobs in the Ubuntu kernel, presumably these are in [`linux-firmware`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=main&arch=any&keywords=linux-firmware&searchon=names) (in main) or [`linux-image-generic`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=main&arch=any&keywords=linux-image-generic&searchon=names) (also in main)? If these blobs are non-free, whey are they included in main which only free software is allowed in?

I note that the Linux kernel is [licensed under the GPL](https://www.kernel.org/category/faq.html), how is this possible if the binary blobs included are not free software, how are they redistributable?

<sub>I came across this question whilst [trying to remove a [citation needed] tag on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)#Package_classification_and_support).</sub>

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/387551/does-ubuntu-contain-non-free-kernel-blobs-and-other-non-free-system-components

Comment: You may be interested in https://www.fsfla.org/ikiwiki/selibre/linux-libre/ which leads to http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-system-distribution-guidelines.html and then http://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html  . Trisquel is ubuntu based https://trisquel.info/ and Parabola is based on arch linux - https://www.parabola.nu/ . Many of the other distros are not as well maintained. You can get the libre kernel from here - http://linux-libre.fsfla.org/pub/linux-libre/releases/

Comment: @Rinzwind My question is more specifically why Linux is in main if it is not actually free software and/or how Linux can be GPL if it includes nonfree software.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're talking about this part:

> Free software includes software that has met the Ubuntu licensing
>   requirements,<sup>[[53](https://www.ubuntu.com/project/about-ubuntu/licensing)]</sup> which roughly correspond to the Debian Free Software
>   Guidelines. Exceptions, however, include firmware and fonts, in the
>   Main category, because although they are not allowed to be modified,
>   their distribution is otherwise unencumbered. <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

And the relevant part about firmware from the the webpage referenced there is:

> #### Documentation, firmware and drivers
>
> Ubuntu contains licensed and copyrighted works that are not
>   application software. For example, the default Ubuntu installation
>   includes documentation, images, sounds, video clips and firmware. The
>   Ubuntu community will make decisions on the inclusion of these works
>   on a case-by-case basis, ensuring that these works do not restrict our
>   ability to make Ubuntu available free of charge, and that you can
>   continue to redistribute Ubuntu.

And a little above that, emphasis mine:

> #### Ubuntu 'main' component licence policy
>
> All application software included in the Ubuntu main component:
>
> - Must include source code. The main component has a strict and non-negotiable requirement that **application software** included in
>     it must come with full source code.

By considering "firmware" as not "application software", they have relaxed the requirement of having their source code be available and modifiable, allowing them to be in `main`.

---

At this point you'd probably need a couple of countries' worth of lawyers, a few dozen courts and appeals, and a high noon to decide the validity of this, but that's not something to be settled *here* on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ThomasWard I'm reasonably certain that's either `main` or `restricted`. For example, `bcmwl-kernel-source` is in the restricted section and has been on images for years now.

Comment: Basically, in a nut shell, ubuntu / debian, and in fact most distors, make exceptions for firmware considering it part of the hardware. From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Firmware "In fact, in almost all cases firmware is treated like hardware in that it's a black box; there's no accompanying source code that is freely distributed with it." and from https://wiki.debian.org/KernelFirmwareLicensing "There are many cases that look suspiciously like the firmware image was grabbed without permission, but we don't try to categorize and second-guess such cases here."